# Binding a gridview's itemSource to the ViewModel with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, binding

I want my ViewModel to loop through all the inner elements of my gridView with the Test() function. My "gridVariable" (see code) returns null for some reason. When getting and setting values to the TextBox, I encounter no problems. Why is the GridView returning null, and how can I fix it?

MainViewModel.cs

```
    public class MainViewModel : Observable, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainViewModel(){}

        private GetGridView _myGridView = new GetGridView();
        public GetGridView MyGridView
        {
            get { return _myGridView; }
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            var gridVariable = MyGridView.AnswersGrid;
            foreach (var i in gridVariable.Items) MyText.Text += "x";
        }

        private GetText _myText = new GetText();
        public GetText MyText
        {
            get { return _myText; }
            set
            {
                _myText = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

GetGridView.cs

```
    public class GetGridView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private GridView _grid;
        public GridView AnswersGrid
        {
            get { return _grid; }
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
    <RelativePanel>
        <GridView
            x:Name="GridView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridView.AnswersGrid, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
            <TextBox/>
        </GridView>
        <Button RelativePanel.Below="GridView" Content="butn" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Test}"></Button>
    </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Binding a gridview's itemSource to the ViewModel with INotifyPropertyChanged

I checked your requirement, if you want use MVVM pattern, you need split `View` and `Model`. I have rewrite your code. please check the following.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item { Info = "01" });
        items.Add(new Item { Info = "02" });
        items.Add(new Item { Info = "03" });
        items.Add(new Item { Info = "04" });
        items.Add(new Item { Info = "05" });
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> items;
    public void Test()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Info += "X";
        }
    }

}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private string _info;
    public string Info
    {
        get
        {
            return _info;
        }
        set
        {
            _info = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<GridView
    x:Name="GridView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.items}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Info}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

</GridView>
<Button RelativePanel.Below="GridView" Content="butn" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Test}"></Button>
```

For more detail info, please refer [**Data binding and MVVM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm)